# error in the syntax of cmd parameters

Tags: sql

hi guyz in this method i m just adding the values to the db.

temp is a object.
the field value and variables in the object re havin the same name..

dono y this error s comin

plz

help me out...

```
public virtual void Save_input_parameter_details(Test_Unit_BLL temp )
        {
            SqlConnection con;
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VV;Initial Catalog=testingtool;User ID=sa;Password=sa;");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd, cmd2, cmd3;
    //try
    //{

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.No_Input_parameters; i++)
            {
                cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Input_parameter_details values(@Input_Parameter_name,@Input_Parameter_datatype,@noparams,@class_code", con);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Input_Parameter_datatype", temp.Input_Parameter_datatype[i]);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Input_Parameter_name", temp.Input_Parameter_name[i]);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noparams", temp.No_Input_parameters);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class_code",temp.class_code);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //    {
            //        MessageBox.Show("error"+ex);
            //    }
        }
```

Comment: should not be there a closing bracket after values in sql statement?

Comment: What's the error message, Katy?

Answer (score 0):

It may be failing based on the unknown actual sequence of columns its trying to push the data into.  You are implying the first X number of columns.  You may need to be explicit in your SQL such as :

```
insert into YourTable ( Fld1, Fld2, Fld3 ) values (@ParmVal1, @ParmVal2, @ParmVal3 );
```

Then do your parameters.add with values...  Additionally, you MAY want to make sure your added parameters are in the same sequence as your SQL statement lists them too.

Answer (score 0):

Do the columns in the table line up with the parameters as you have them listed (1st = input_parameter_name, 2nd = input_parameter_datatype, etc.)?